# Run Code at Certain Time

Tags: ios, core-data, nstimer, data-modeling

I'm building an app based around the user creating recurring 'events'. Each Event object has a day (stored as a typedef NS_ENUM), and a time (stored as an NSDate), and a duration (an NSInteger representing minutes). Each event always repeats weekly. Events are stored in a Core Data managed, cross device synchronised, database. And are designed to be reused such that they don't need to be recreated each week (hence the date independent weekdays). Once an event is finished, some user statistics are updated.

Take, for example, an event that starts on Monday at 10:00, and lasts for 25 minutes. In this case, I would want to get the `NSDate` representation of `this Monday at 10:25` (which isn't a problem) and at this time, update the user statistics, which is the problem.

What is the best way of having code execute at a certain time?

I had originally thought of using `[[NSDate alloc] initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]`. However, it would be difficult to ensure the `target` object was initialised, and to synchronise the timers between devices. That is to say, make sure each timer is set to fire at the same time (should the day, time, or duration change).

My second thought, was to update the statistics when the apps launched, using the current system time, and looking back at previous events. However, if the user has the app open, I want the statistics to update in real time.

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated. I am also open to ideas on how I might change my model to better solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible situations that your app can be in when the timer needs to fire - it's either in the foreground or not. NSTimer will only fire when the app is in the foreground (with a few minor exceptions, such as running in a background execution task).

You could handle the two situations as follows:

- Schedule the timer for the next required time, using initWithFireDate. You should set the target to an object that will exist while your app is running. You could use your UIApplicationDelegate or some other singleton class.
- When the app goes to background, invalidate the time.
- When the app returns to foreground, check if the timer should have fired since the app was last put to background. If so, run the statistics update. Schedule the next timer task.
- If the timer fires, the app is still in the foreground so run the statistics update task, then schedule the next timer task.